# Access object value?

Tags: php

I have object as a result of an SQL query that is structured like this:

```
object(Database)#2 (5) {
  ["pdo":"Database":private]=>
  object(PDO)#3 (0) {
  }
  ["query":"Database":private]=>
  object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) {
    ["queryString"]=>
    string(42) "SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `some_id`=?"
  }
  ["results":"Database":private]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "20"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "30"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "31"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "32"
    }
  }
```

How would I go about accessing values from id fields? Tried casting to array, but that failed.

Comment: `results` is a property of __what__ object?

Comment: Also, it is a private property, so only the class code can access it.

Comment: Updated with full var_dump result.

Answer (score 1):

I fugured it out. I have to go `->results()` and then access index and id field `[0]->id`.